# How to access content_main.xml elements in MainActivity.kt by using ViewBinding in Android Studio 4.1?

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

For example, I want to access RecyclerView(Id recycler_view) elements in content_main.xml by Mainactivity.kt.
content_main.xml is in activity_main.xml.

```
class PhotoDetailsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var binding: ContentMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))
        binding = ContentMain.inflate(layoutInflater)
        binding.recycler_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
....

    }
}
```

But this way does not work. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```kotlin
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))
        binding = ContentMain.inflate(layoutInflater)
```

with:

```kotlin
        binding = ContentMain.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
```

You need to use the `root` of your inflated `binding` with `setContentView()` for the binding to work.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought root means content_main.xml

Answer (score 2):

In this case view binding will create a reference to the included layout’s binding object. You need to set id for `<include>` tag for view binding to generate a property. In this case

```
 <include layout="@layout/content_main"
            android:id="@+id/main_container"/>
```

Then while accessing `RecyclerView` in `PhotoDetailsActivity`,

```
 binding.main_container.recycler_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one. it works for me. when you are in main activity, and created binding reference like below, you can access all views(textview, edittext, button etc) in Main Activity by this reference.

```
private  lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)

binding.textView  // for example
```

and if you want to access view elements from content_main layout then use this code:

```
binding.root.findViewById<Button>(R.id.myButton).setOnClickListener { view ->

           //some action code
        }
```

and it works!